# SQL syntax error creating table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner programmer in MySQL. When I'm creating a table called `message` in my database called `chat`, this is the error:

> Error creating Table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from CHAR(30),to TEXT(300),text TEXT(1000),index INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1

The full MySQL statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE message(date DATE,from CHAR(30),to TEXT(300),text TEXT(1000),index INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(index))
```

I know the other code is correct, because I created another table previously, and it worked fine. I then copied the code and used it for this statement.

It's probably a really silly mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest to avoid using reserved words for columns/tables etc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to`, `from` and `index` are [**reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE message(date DATE,`from` CHAR(30),`to` TEXT(300),text TEXT(1000),`index` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(`index`))
```

Comment: You have to quote the last `index` occurrence, too.

Answer (score 1):

`from` is a mysql reserved words,

you must add from in `,

UPDATE: to,index is key too, here the right sql

```
CREATE TABLE message(date DATE,`from` CHAR(30),`to` TEXT(300),text TEXT(1000),`index` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(`index`))
```